# Use timestamp as normal time

Tags: php, mysql, timestamp

I'd like to "transform" the CURRENT_TIMESTAMP from the MySQL field type timestamp into a more readable format, such as:

2011-03-20 14:05:34

to

March 20 at 2:05 PM

But I'd also like to use a variable to make the time be in 24h format,

March 20 at 14:05

What PHP code could I use to do such?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

using [date()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) with [strtotime()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php) it is good place to start...

```
echo date ( 'F j G:i', strtotime ( $row [ 'timestamp' ] ) );
```

Answer (score 1):

Date_format is your friend :)

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format

```
select date_format('2011-03-20 14:05:34','%M %d at %H:%i') as my_date ....
```